Compute weight of modular form from its Fourier coefficients
It is known that Hecke eigenform $f \in S_{k}(\Gamma_0(N), \chi)$ is uniquely determined by first $C_{k,N}$ many Fourier coefficients, where $C_{k,N}$ is a constant only depends on $k$ and $N$. For example, for fixed weight $k$, Strum's bound tells us that we can take $C_{k, N} = \frac{k}{12}[\operatorname{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}): \Gamma_0(N)]$ when $\chi =1$. We can even distinguish eigenforms of different weights: if $f \in S_{k_1}(\Gamma_0(N))$ and $g \in S_{k_2}(\Gamma_0(N))$ are eigenforms and $a_n(f) = a_n(g)$ for all $n \leq 4(\log(N) + 1)^2$, then $k_1 = k_2$ and $f = g$ (by Ghitza).
Now I wonder if there's any efficient algorithm to compute weight of an eigenform $f$ from its Fourier coefficients $a_n(f)$, assuming that we can compute it as much as we want (let's assume that we also don't know the level of $f$). A naive idea arising from my head is to observe their asymptotes and use Sato-Tate theorem, to find the right power $k$ such that $a_{p}(f) / 2p^{(k-1)/2}$. To be precise, we can try to plot $\log a_p(f) / \log p$ for many $p$'s and "guess" what is the correct $k$. This is certainly not an efficient algorithm, and I'm not sure if this is even deterministic. (I haven't tried this method myself yet though)
We can actually ask the same question for Maass forms, and it gets much harder. Still by multiplicity one theorem, Fourier coefficients of Maass forms determine themselves, which means that if we know all Fourier coefficients of a Maass form, it determines its eigenvalue $\lambda$ for Laplacian. So our goal is to guess $\lambda$ from $a_n(f)$'s (for simiplicity, let's only consider weight 0 Maass forms). But as far as I know, there's no analogous result as Strum's bound or Ghitza's theorem for Maass forms, and Sato-Tate approach above also fails.

Edit 1: If we have no restrictions for $n$ of $a_n$, then Chris Wuthrich's comment works very well. Although we assume that we don't know the level $N$ of $f$, we can "easily" find a prime $p$ such that $a_{p^{2}}(f) \neq a_{p}(f)^{2}$ (if $N$ is something like $N = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot ... \cdot 1009$, then this may needs a bit more effort), then $a_{p^2}(f) - a_{p}(f)^{2} = \chi(p) p^{k-1}$ gives $$k = \log |a_{p^{2}}(f) - a_{p}(f)^{2}| / \log p + 1$$
Maybe it is not a good move to change a question, but I guess more interesting variant is to assume that we only knows $a_p(f)$ for prime $p$ and we don't know $\chi$.

If $a_1=1$, then $a_{p^2} - (a_p)^2$ is $\chi(p)\cdot p^{k-1}$. If this is non-zero for a prime $p$, you get $k$.

@ChrisWuthrich That’s great! So even if we don’t know $\chi$, it has finite order and $|\chi(p)|=1$, so we get $k$ (it should be easy to find such $p$, since we only need $p$ to be coprime to level). Can this method be  extended to the situation when we only know $a_p$’s for prime $p$? Of course you already answered my original question, but this seems more interesting for me.

I haven't thought about this, but can't you use the modular transformation law on the part of the Fourier expansion that you know?  Or alternatively uses Deligne's bound to get a lower bound on $k$, and then try applying Hecke operators weights starting with that bound till you find something compatible.

@Kimball You mean to approximate $f(z)$ with truncated expansion and compare something like $f(it)$ and $f(i/t)$ (for the first approach)? I understand the second approach, which looks good too.
